# Tournament not ending in multiplayer cocos2dx game using nextpeer

Tags: android, ios, cocos2d-x, nextpeer

I have successfully integrated nextpeer in my game and its working fine. I can log in with facebook, connect with my friends and play. However when the match ends, it keeps stating in "Your matches" tab that there are still 2 days left to play and is showing my score and my friends'. Shouldn't this tournament have ended since I called and it is a game controlled tournament?

CCNextpeer::getInstance()->reportControlledTournamentOverWithScore((int)_score);

How do I end this match without the time thats shown above. Also the leaderboard isnt updating. When and how does the leaderboard update. There isn't much information about it on next peers integration manuals.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are talking about the match time between Facebook friend. 
Nextpeer's default is 72 hours per match with a friend. You can customize that in our dashboard settings. For more, read here https://nextpeer.atlassian.net/wiki/display/DEV/iOS#iOS-FacebookmatchTimeToLive.

Our support team can assist you with the configuration. Feel free to contact them with any question, support[at]nextpeer[dot]com.